# Magento - Sell Products by gram

Tags: magento, configuration, product

Hi i want to sell products by gram.

For example i'll define 1g=0.015€.

On the product page the customers should input for example 250g.

Which product-type/configuration matches this requirement at best?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use simple product with as `custom option` for weight of type `text field`.
Add some javascript to change the price on product detail page.

For adding to cart, you need an observer.
You have to build an observer that catches the add-to-cart event `sales_quote_add_item` and then you can do the php-stuff in the observer to get the weight and calculate the price.

You can then change the price of the product with:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()->setOriginalCustomPrice([your price])
```